# Vertical align middle for after class in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following button code which works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome.

After the button text there is a small down arrow which is not properly sitting in middle (vertically) in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="button uppercase white">home</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/16scmbcr/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it works for me. I'm using 42.0.2311.135

Comment: it's sitting ok in chrome, but you can try to give position relative on button:after and play with top property.

Comment: Make sure you have the newest version of google chrome and try to close the browser and load the website again

Comment: Applying the same line-height to both the button text and the :after-declaration will fix the issue as long as the character itself is vertically centered within its font definition char box.

Comment: @connexo After a long research I found the problem is with the custom font which I am using.